# Facing ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

[image]I am working on image dataset that consist of 12 multiple classes. I am using transfer learning to make classification. As a result I am using VGG19. But I am facing an error that is ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.

My code:

```
def create_gen():
    # Load the Images with a generator and Data Augmentation
    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input,
        validation_split=0.1
    )

    test_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input
    )

    train_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Label',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=0,
        subset='training',
        rotation_range=30, # Uncomment to use data augmentation
        zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest"
    )

    val_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Label',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=0,
        subset='validation',
        rotation_range=30, # Uncomment to use data augmentation
        zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest"
    )

    test_images = test_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=test_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Label',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=False
    )
    
    return train_generator,test_generator,train_images,val_images,test_images

# Separate in train and test data
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(image_df, train_size=0.9, shuffle=True, random_state=1)

# Create the generators
train_generator,test_generator,train_images,val_images,test_images = create_gen()

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
vggmodel = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

for layers in (vggmodel.layers)[:32]:
    print(layers)
    layers.trainable = False

X= vggmodel.layers[-12].output
x= tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(X)
predictions = Dense(12, activation="softmax")(x)
model_final = Model(vggmodel.input, predictions)

model_final.compile(optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0003), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Detail Error:

```
<keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7f16263fdbd0>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f1625a80c50>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f1625ab0290>
<keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f1610041990>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f161006acd0>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f16100706d0>
<keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f161006d810>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f15d81ad910>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f15d81b1050>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f15d81b7dd0>
<keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f1626228990>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f15d81c1290>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f15d81c3910>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f15d81c1950>
<keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f162649b690>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f15d81d5b90>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f15d81db850>
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f15d81cffd0>
<keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f15d81b7b50>
<keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x7f1625ab0450>
<keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f1610070b50>
<keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f15d81afc90>
<keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f15d81e5150>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-485f259e81f1> in <module>()
      5 
      6 X= vggmodel.layers[-12].output
----> 7 x= tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(X)
      8 predictions = Dense(12, activation="softmax")(x)
      9 model_final = Model(vggmodel.input, predictions)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

Comment: Seems you need some `if thing is None: ` checks ...

Comment: Could you please precise it @PatrickArtner

Comment: Can you try to import all from `import tensorflow.*` instead of `import keras.*`? If It doesn't, please share complete code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!